# jquery UI draggable jumps on screen scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

My jquery UI draggable is working great, except when I try to drag something off-screen, causing the screen to scroll.  Then the selected item jumps to who knows where - you can't see it anymore.  Anyone know how I can troubleshoot this?  Thank you.

Right now we are on jquery-ui-1.8.24 and jquery-1.8.2

Comment: oops, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820826/jquery-uis-draggable-and-page-scrolling and http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the element style which you are `appendTo` should be `position: relative` When using jQuery-ui `draggable`

Answer (score 1):

After failing to find a solution for this with jQuery, I implemented my own drag - works good for me.
It also allowed me to remove jQuery UI, which was great.
Notice that draggable and handle are jquery elements, and limits is an object.
Here is the code -

```
function initializeDrag(draggable, handle, limits) {
                            var initialMousePosition, initialDraggablePosition;
                            handle.on('mousedown', function (e) {
                                initialMousePosition = {
                                    x: e.pageX,
                                    y: e.pageY
                                };
                                initialDraggablePosition = {
                                    top: parseInt(draggable.css('top'), 10),
                                    left: parseInt(draggable.css('left'), 10)
                                }
                                document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                                document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
                            });

                            function onMouseMove(e) {
                                var verticalDelta = e.pageY - initialMousePosition.y;
                                var horizontalDelta = e.pageX - initialMousePosition.x;
                                var topRes = initialDraggablePosition.top + verticalDelta;
                                var leftRes = initialDraggablePosition.left + horizontalDelta;
                                topRes = Math.max(topRes, limits.top);
                                topRes = Math.min(topRes, limits.bottom);
                                leftRes = Math.max(leftRes, limits.left);
                                leftRes = Math.min(leftRes, limits.right);

                                draggable.css({
                                    top: topRes + 'px',
                                    left: leftRes + 'px'
                                });
                            }

                            function onMouseUp() {
                                document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                                document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/g4xHG/

If you set the overflow property on the `body` element, this problem goes away. No idea why.

```
body {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: that jsfiddle is set to jQuery 1.8.3 / jQuery UI 1.9.2. I thought that was close enough as the problem re-appeared when the body css was removed